# How do I obtain the X values corresponding to a given probability value using probplot, Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to obtain the corresponding X value for a given probability value in the probplot command in Matlab.

```
    % Input Data 

    X = [   78572.12124
             85385.44766
             71947.35964
             87050.1572
             77451.33935
             54705.93013
             69341.39769
             63182.64207
             71262.53291 ];

    % Plotting lognormal proabability plot with reference line

    h1 = probplot('lognormal', X);

    % Obtain the X and Y coordinates of the reference line 

    Xcoord = h1(2).XData';
    Ycoord = h1(2).YData';

    % Note the Y data is in quantiles, it could be converted to proabability
    % values

    Ycoord_probability = normcdf(Ycoord);

    % How do I obtain the Xcoord corresponding to Ycoord_probability = 1e-3
    % (say) ??
```

Answer (score 0):

From a Matlab standpoint, you can do the following.

```
Xcoord_queried = interp1(Ycoord_probability, Xcoord, Ycoord_probability_queried);
```

where `Ycoord_probability_queried` is 1e-3 in your example and the output is the answer I believe you are looking for. See more [info on interpolation in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation.html).

From a math standpoint, perhaps you are better off fitting a lognormal distribution to your data set, using `fitdist` for example, and retrieve information from the fitted distribution itself.